# Integrating Redmine with Mylyn in Zend Studio 8.0.0

Tags: eclipse, redmine, zend-studio, mylyn

We're trying to use Redmine as our issue tracker.
I use Zend Studio 8.0.0 for PHP. I'd like to integrate Redmine with the IDE.

The most important features I want are these:

- Synchronizing the tracked time in eclipse with Redmine (This is the most important feature I want)
- Having multiple projects in a single Redmine repository
- Being able to add or see tasks in a rich editor inside eclipse (not in the browser)

First I tried to install the [native redmine-mylyn connector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/), but it had dependency problems:

`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Mylyn Connector: Redmine 0.1.0.201012302120 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201012302120)‍‍`

`Missing requirement: Mylyn Connector: Redmine 0.1.0.201012302120 (net.sf.redmine_mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201012302120) requires 'org.json 1.0.0' but it could not be found`

I don't know how to install this **org.json 1.0.0** plugin.

Then I tried the generic web connector (as described [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn)), it worked to some extent, but I didn't get the features I wanted.

Anyone can help pleaaaaaaaaase?!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same problem and found solution [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3058076&group_id=228995&atid=1075435).

Go to: 
Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software sites
and check Eclipse site.

Comment: Thanks! I checked some of the update sites (all of them start with http://download.eclipse.org ) and then I could install it.